# Target a specific email notification with the email id in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I have custom statuses and custom emails set up in WooCommerce. I would like to use the current email, `WC_Email`, not the current status as a variable inside email templates.

I need to have some if statements in the email templates. I am not using the order status to ensure if an email from an order gets resent manually it doesn't send data for the current order status with an separate email.

How can I echo the `WC_Email` email ID as a variable in WooCommerce?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `wc_order_email` class or function doesn't exist in WooCommerce, so I have updated your question.

What you are looking at is `$email` variable argument *(the [**`WC_Email`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Email.html) current type object)*. It's mostly defined everywhere in templates and hooks.

To get the usable current Email ID as a variable you will simply use `$email_id = $email->id`…

To get the current Email ID of your custom emails, you should use this code *(just for **testing**)*:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', 'get_the_wc_email_id', 9, 4 );
function get_the_wc_email_id( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    // Will output the email id for the current notification
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($email->id); echo '</pre>'; 
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

You will get one of the following:

1. For WooCommerce default notifications:

   - `new_order`
   - `customer_on_hold_order`
   - `customer_processing_order`
   - `customer_completed_order`
   - `customer_refunded_order`
   - `customer_partially_refunded_order`
   - `cancelled_order`
   - `failed_order`
   - `customer_reset_password`
   - `customer_invoice`
   - `customer_new_account`
   - `customer_note`
   - `low_stock`
   - `no_stock`
2. For WooCommerce Subscriptions:

   - `new_renewal_order`
   - `new_switch_order`
   - `customer_processing_renewal_order`
   - `customer_completed_renewal_order`
   - `customer_on_hold_renewal_order`
   - `customer_completed_switch_order`
   - `customer_renewal_invoice`
   - `cancelled_subscription`
   - `expired_subscription`
   - `suspended_subscription`
3. For WooCommerce Bookings:

   - `new_booking`
   - `booking_reminder`
   - `booking_confirmed`
   - `booking_pending_confirmation`
   - `booking_notification`
   - `booking_cancelled`
   - `admin_booking_cancelled`
4. For WooCommerce Memberships:

   - `WC_Memberships_User_Membership_Note_Email`
   - `WC_Memberships_User_Membership_Ending_Soon_Email`
   - `WC_Memberships_User_Membership_Ended_Email`
   - `WC_Memberships_User_Membership_Renewal_Reminder_Email`
   - `WC_Memberships_User_Membership_Activated_Email`

Once you get the **correct email ID slug** for your custom email notification you can use it on any following hook *(instead of overriding email templates)*:

- `woocommerce_email_header` *(2 arguments: `$email_heading`, `$email`)*
- `woocommerce_email_order_details` *(4 arguments: `$order`, `$sent_to_admin`, `$plain_text`, `$email`)*
- `woocommerce_email_order_meta` *(4 arguments: `$order`, `$sent_to_admin`, `$plain_text`, `$email`)*
- `woocommerce_email_customer_details` *(4 arguments: `$order`, `$sent_to_admin`, `$plain_text`, `$email`)*
- `woocommerce_email_footer` *(1 argument: `$email`)*

HERE an **example of code** where I target "New order" email notifications only:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', 'add_custom_text_to_new_order_email', 10, 4 );
function add_custom_text_to_new_order_email( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    // Only for "New Order"  email notifications (to be replaced by yours)
    if( ! ( 'new_order' == $email->id ) ) return;

    // Display a custom text (for example)
    echo '<p>'.__('My custom text').'</p>';
}
```

*Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin)*.