# Remove Order # from WooCommerce "Order on-hold" & "New Order" Emails

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, email-notifications

I'd like to remove the auto-generated order number from both the "Order on-hold" and "New order" emails generated by WooCommerce.

I'm using a third-party plugin to assign custom order numbers after an order has been placed, so it's important that the new order number I assign can still be used in future emails. I don't want the customer (or admin) to see the original order number until it has been changed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated** *(only for woocommerce 3.3+ specific template)*

You will need to override a Woocommerce email template via your child theme as explained on the below linked official documentation:

[Template structure & Overriding templates via a theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)

The template to copy and override is `woocommerce/templates/emails/email-order-details.php`

In this template (copied to your theme as explained) you will need to change this entire block:

```
<h2>
    <?php
    if ( $sent_to_admin ) {
        $before = '<a class="link" href="' . esc_url( $order->get_edit_order_url() ) . '">';
        $after  = '</a>';
    } else {
        $before = '';
        $after  = '';
    }
    /* translators: %s: Order ID. */
    echo wp_kses_post( $before . sprintf( __( 'Order #%s', 'woocommerce' ) . $after . ' (<time datetime="%s">%s</time>)', $order->get_order_number(), $order->get_date_created()->format( 'c' ), wc_format_datetime( $order->get_date_created() ) ) );
    ?>
</h2>
```

to:

```
<?php
    // Targetting specific email notificatoins
    $email_ids = array('new_order', 'customer_on_hold_order');

    $date = sprintf( '<time datetime="%s">%s</time>', $order->get_date_created()->format( 'c' ), wc_format_datetime( $order->get_date_created() ) );

    // Displaying order number except for "New Order" and "Customer On Hold Order" notifications
    if( ! in_array($email->id, $email_ids) ){
        $order_number = sprintf( __( 'Order #%s', 'woocommerce' ), $order->get_order_number() );
        $date = '('.$date.')';
    } else {
        $date = __('Order date:', 'woocommerce') . ' ' . $date;
        $order_number = '';
    }

    if ( $sent_to_admin ) {
        $before = '<a class="link" href="' . esc_url( $order->get_edit_order_url() ) . '">';
        $after  = '</a> ';
    } else {
        $before = '';
        $after  = ' ';
    }
?>

<h2><?php echo $before . $order_number . $after . $date; ?></h2>
```

This will remove the Order number on "New Order" and "Customer On Hold Order" email notifications. You will get:

1) New order (admin):

[image]

2) Customer On-Hold Order:

[image]

Now you will also need in WooCommerce > Settings > Emails to remove  `({order_number})` from "New Order" subject and save…

[image]

You are done…

Comment: Firstly, THANK YOU for the quick response! However, I'm not seeing the first block of code you're referring to in the [email-order-details.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/3.3/templates/emails/email-order-details.php) template file. I see a similar block wrapped in an <h2> but replacing that with the code you provided doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something? I'm on a multisite network, but I don't think that should make a difference.

Comment: @RBaum I have updated the code, now it will match… Sorry as I didn't get the right template that has changed with woocommerce 3.3.

Answer (score 0):

**REMOVE ORDER NUMBER VIA CSS**

If you don't want to override the email templates you can use the [**`woocommerce_email_styles`**](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-emails-class-wc-email.html#source-view.560) hook to add a simple CSS rule that hides the order number in WooCommerce email.

This hook is activated just after the template is loaded: `/woocommerce/emails/email-styles.php`

> To hide the order number only for the "Order on-hold" and "New Order"
> templates you can use the second $ email argument of the
> woocommerce_email_styles hook to check the id. Find a list here: [Targeting specific email with the email id in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47742782/10447197).

```
// hides the order number in the email templates
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_styles', 'add_woocommerce_email_styles', 10, 2 );
function add_woocommerce_email_styles( $css, $email ) {
    // define the ids of the emails for which you want to add CSS rules
    $email_ids = array(
        'new_order',
        'customer_on_hold_order'
    );
    // adds CSS rules to these emails only
    if ( in_array( $email->id, $email_ids ) ) {
        $css .= 'div[id^="body_content_inner"] > h2 { display: none; }';
    }
    return $css;
}
```

*The code has been tested and works. Add it to your active theme's functions.php.*

**ADD THE NEW ORDER NUMBER**

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66292926/10447197) you can also **add the new order number**, like so:

```
// adds the new order number before the order table in the completed order email
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'add_content_before_order_table', 99, 4 );
function add_content_before_order_table( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    // define the ids of the emails for which you want to add CSS rules
    $email_ids = array(
        'new_order',
        'customer_on_hold_order'
    );
    // adds CSS rules to these emails only
    if ( in_array( $email->id, $email_ids ) ) {
        echo '<p>New order number</p>'; // do not use the <h2> tag otherwise it will be hidden
    }
}
```

*The code has been tested and works. Add it to your active theme's functions.php.*