# Send email to client or user when creating product with woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to be able to send emails to specific users or clients when creating a product using woocommerce

When a product is created, I want to send out an email like an invoice requesting the emailed user to come and make the payment on the website

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Does this link answer your question ?  [Targeting specific email with the email id in Woocommerce] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47741577/targeting-specific-email-with-the-email-id-in-woocommerce)

Comment: Not really... Those are for completed orders... I'm looking at placing a form in the add products section so after the product has been created, the system would send an email with the product details to the recepient address in the form