# How to edit additional content in WooCommerce emails?

Tags: email, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I would like to edit the additional content for specific WooCommerce emails. Is there any hook filter to do this?

I have just managed to change the Heading text with a filter `woocommerce_email_heading_customer_completed_order`.

I would also like to do this for the additional content.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [**`'woocommerce_email_additional_content_' . $this->id`**](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-emails-class-wc-email.html#source-view.372).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47742782/10447197) you find a complete list of email ids.

So in your case:

- `woocommerce_email_additional_content_customer_refunded_order` for full refund
- `woocommerce_email_additional_content_customer_partially_refunded_order` for partial refund

Try this:

```
// edit the additional content of the "Refunded order" email
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_additional_content_customer_refunded_order', 'custom_additional_content_customer_refunded_order', 99, 3 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_additional_content_customer_partially_refunded_order', 'custom_additional_content_customer_refunded_order', 99, 3 );
function custom_additional_content_customer_refunded_order( $content, $object, $email ) {
    $content = 'Your personalized additional content';
    return $content;
}
```

*The code has been tested and works. Add it to your active theme's functions.php.*

Comment: Thanks. And thanks for the links also. Now I have a good understanding of how it works. Unfortunatelly, some people voted the question down as they could not understand it. You are brilliant