# How to add Product names on the Email subject in Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-email

I have found many PHP codes shared on this platform for adding product name in the subject field in Woocommerce emails.

But when I add the snippets, Checkout is not working "Error processing checkout. Please try again."

Here is the code

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_format_string' , 'add_custom_email_format_string', 10, 2 );
    function add_custom_email_format_string( $string, $email ) {
        $order          = $email->object; // Get the instance of the WC_Order OBJECT
        $products_names = array();

        // Loop through order items
        foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
            $products_names[] = $item->get_name();
        };

        // Replace placeholders with their respective values
        $string = str_replace( '{biller_fname}', $order->billing_first_name(), $string );
        $string = str_replace( '{biller_lname}', $order->billing_last_name(), $string );
        $string = str_replace( '{biller_email}', $order->billing_email(), $string );
        $string = str_replace( '{product_name}', implode(' ', $products_names), $string );
        $string = str_replace( '{blog_name}', get_bloginfo('name'), $string );

        return $string;
    }
```

Any updated code that works? Please share it

Also, mention the tag which I can add it on the email settings... Like "{product_name}

Answer (score 0):

First, here is a utility function to get the formatted product names string from an order *(that we will use in both ways after)*:

```php
function get_formatted_product_names_string( $order ) {
    $placeholder_data = array();

    // Loop through order items
    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        $product  = $item->get_product();
        $quantity = $item->get_quantity();
        $placeholder_data[] = $quantity . ' &times; ' . $product->get_name();
    };

    return implode(', ', $placeholder_data);
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin).

---

Now, there are **2 ways** to add product names to the email subject…

##### 1) Using placeholders:

Add The following code additionally:

```php
// REQUIRES get_formatted_product_names_string() custom utility function

add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_format_string' , 'custom_email_format_string_placeholder', 10, 2 );
function custom_email_format_string_placeholder( $string, $email ) {
    $order          = $email->object; // Get the instance of the WC_Order OBJECT
    if ( is_a($order, 'WC_Order') ) {
        // Replace placeholders with their respective values
        $string = str_replace( '{products}', get_formatted_product_names_string( $order ), $string );
    }
    return $string;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

Then go to WooCommerce Settings > Emails, and for each desired email notification, you will have to add the placeholder `{products}` to the email subject *(see the example below)*.

Here we start for **"New Order" notification** *(click on "manage" button)*. 
Add `[{site_title}]: New order #{order_number} | Products: {products}` text to the Email subject field and "save Changes".

[image]

---

##### 2) Editing each email type using a filter hook:

Here we will use the composite filter hook `'woocommerce_email_subject_' . $email_id`.

For **email IDs** see: [Target a specific email notification with the email id in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47741577/target-a-specific-email-notification-with-the-email-id-in-woocommerce/47742782#47742782)

Here below, we will handle the New Order email notification:

```php
// REQUIRES get_formatted_product_names_string() function

add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_subject_new_order', 'custom_new_order_email_subject', 20, 2 );
function custom_new_order_email_subject( $formated_subject, $order ){
    return sprintf( __('[%s] New order #%s | Products: %s', 'woocommerce'), 
        get_bloginfo('name'), // Site name
        $order->get_order_number(), // Order number (or order ID)
        get_formatted_product_names_string( $order )
    );
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.