# Update order status from order confirmation email in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to add 2 buttons in the order confirmation email: "Confirm order" and "Cancel order". When one of these buttons is pressed, the customer should be taken to a confirmation URL on my website and the status of the order should be updated accordingly ("completed" for confirmed orders and "canceled" for canceled).

What I tried:

1. Created a custom endpoint to handle the action triggered by the buttons:

```
// Add this code to your theme's functions.php file or create a custom plugin.
add_action('init', 'custom_order_actions');

function custom_order_actions() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint('confirm-order', EP_ROOT);
    add_rewrite_endpoint('cancel-order', EP_ROOT);
}
```

2. Edited order confirmation email template (buttons do not show up)

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url(wc_get_order_url($order->get_id()) . 'confirm-order'); ?>" class="button" style="color:#ffffff; background-color:#4CAF50; text-decoration: none;">Confirm Order</a>

<a href="<?php echo esc_url(wc_get_order_url($order->get_id()) . 'cancel-order'); ?>" class="button" style="color:#ffffff; background-color:#ff0000; text-decoration: none;">Cancel Order</a>
```

3. Handle button actions

```
// Confirm Order
add_action('template_redirect', 'confirm_order_action');

function confirm_order_action() {
    global $wp;
    if (isset($wp->query_vars['confirm-order'])) {
        // Update order status to completed
        $order_id = absint($_GET['order_id']);
        $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
        $order->update_status('completed');
        // Redirect to confirmation page
        wp_redirect(home_url('/order-confirmed'));
        exit;
    }
}

// Cancel Order
add_action('template_redirect', 'cancel_order_action');

function cancel_order_action() {
    global $wp;
    if (isset($wp->query_vars['cancel-order'])) {
        // Update order status to cancelled
        $order_id = absint($_GET['order_id']);
        $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
        $order->update_status('cancelled');
        // Redirect to confirmation page
        wp_redirect(home_url('/order-cancelled'));
        exit;
    }
}
```

Is my logic correct or is there an easier way to accomplish this? Currently, I can't get the buttons to show in the confirmation email. I have added the code in woocommerce/emails/templates.

Comment: There is no "confirmation email" template in WooCommerce, so in what template exactly (file name) did you added the buttons code? The template used in the email notification sent to the customer is defined by the order status… Instead of editing the template itself, you can use one of the available hooks for that…

Comment: I put it in customer-processing-order.php, but the buttons do not show up in the email that the customer receives when placing an order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some mistakes and missing things in your code…

Also, instead of overriding the template file `customer-processing-order.php`, always try to use available hooks…

Try the following replacement code instead *(for "Customer processing Order" notification)*:

```php
// Add custom endpoints
add_action('init', 'custom_wc_order_endpoints');
function custom_wc_order_endpoints() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint('confirm-order', EP_ROOT );
    add_rewrite_endpoint('cancel-order', EP_ROOT );
}

// Set custom endpoints as query variables
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'custom_wc_order_query_vars', 0 );
function custom_wc_order_query_vars( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'confirm-order';
    $vars[] = 'cancel-order';
    return $vars;
}

// Flush rewrite rules for those custom endpoints
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'flush_rewrite_rules_enable_custom_endpoints' );
function flush_rewrite_rules_enable_custom_endpoints() {
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}

// Display 2 custom buttons in "Customer processing Order" email notification
add_action('woocommerce_email_order_meta', 'add_linked_buttons_after_email_order_details', 5, 4 );
function add_linked_buttons_after_email_order_details( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    // Target "Customer processing Order" notification
    if( $email->id !== 'customer_processing_order' ) return;

    printf( '<a href="%s" class="button" style="color:#ffffff; background-color:#4CAF50; text-decoration:none;">%s</a>', 
        wc_get_endpoint_url('confirm-order', $order->get_id(), site_url() ), __('Confirm Order', 'woocommerce') );

    printf( '<a href="%s" class="button" style="color:#ffffff; background-color:#ff0000; text-decoration:none;">%s</a>', 
        wc_get_endpoint_url('cancel-order', $order->get_id(), site_url() ), __('Cancel Order', 'woocommerce') );
}

// Update order status once customer has clicked on a custom button
add_action('template_redirect', 'custom_order_actions');
function custom_order_actions() {
    global $wp;

    if ( isset($wp->query_vars['confirm-order']) ) {
        $order_id     = absint($wp->query_vars['confirm-order']);
        $order_status = 'completed';
    } elseif ( isset($wp->query_vars['cancel-order']) ) {
        $order_id     = absint($wp->query_vars['cancel-order']);
        $order_status = 'cancelled';
    }
    if ( isset($order_status, $order_id) && $order_id > 0 ) {
        $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

        if ( is_a($order, 'WC_Order') ) {
            $order->update_status($order_status); // Update order status
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

**IMPORTANT:**
To get this code working may require to refresh WordPress Permalinks by going to: 
**Settings** > **Permalinks** and click on "Save changes" button.

---

###### ADDITION 
Adding a custom redirection once the order status get updated:

To add a custom redirection *(built on OP comment requirement)* once the order status is updated, replace the last function with the following one:

```php
// Update order status once customer has clicked on a custom button
add_action('template_redirect', 'custom_order_actions');
function custom_order_actions() {
    global $wp;

    if ( isset($wp->query_vars['confirm-order']) ) {
        $endpoint     = 'confirm-order';
        $order_id     = absint($wp->query_vars[$endpoint]);
        $order_status = 'completed';
    } elseif ( isset($wp->query_vars['cancel-order']) ) {
        $endpoint     = 'cancel-order';
        $order_id     = absint($wp->query_vars[$endpoint]);
        $order_status = 'cancelled';
    }
    if ( isset($order_status, $order_id) && $order_id > 0 ) {
        $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

        if ( is_a($order, 'WC_Order') ) {
            $order->update_status($order_status); // Update order status
             
            // Custom redirection
            wp_redirect(site_url("/{$endpoint}/order-{$order_status}"));
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Useful: [Target a specific email notification with the email id in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47741577/target-a-specific-email-notification-with-the-email-id-in-woocommerce/47742782#47742782)

Comment: Thank you for your input. From your code, I understand that when a user clicks the confirm-order button, he is redirected to ```http://example.com/confirm-order/{order_id}```. How do redirect the user to a more generic URL like ```http://example.com/confirm-order/order-confirmed```?

Comment: As `…confirm-order/{order_id}` is required to get the Order ID in the last function (to update the order status), I have added a code addition/replacement to my answer, that will make a redirection to the desired/required URL … Check it, it should work as you expect.