# How to send all Woocommerce emails to an additional email address?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, email-notifications

I am looking to send all emails to another email in order to parse them (using Sendgrid inbound parse).

This is what I currently have:

```
function custom_add_email_address_to_emails( $headers, $object ) {
    $additional_email = 'additional@example.com';
    $headers .= 'Cc: ' . $additional_email . "\r\n";
    return $headers;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'custom_add_email_address_to_emails', 10, 2 );
```

CC-ing, unfortunately, doesn’t seem to work for inbound parse, so I need to actually add the email as a recipient. Do you know how I might do this?

Comment: what if you get all emails, then write a simple loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add recipients to WooCommerce pre-defined email notifications using the composite hook `woocommerce_email_recipient_{$email_id}`.

In the code below:

1. You will define the desired email notifications in the first function *(See [this linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47741577/target-a-specific-email-notification-with-the-email-id-in-woocommerce/47742782#47742782) for other email IDs)*,
2. You will define the desired additional recipient (emails) in the 2nd function.

The code:

```php
add_action('woocommerce_init', 'additional_email_recipient_for_notifications');
function additional_email_recipient_for_notifications(){
    // HERE below define the desired email notification
    $email_ids = array(
        'new_order',
        'customer_on_hold_order', 
        'customer_processing_order',
        'customer_completed_order',
        'customer_refunded_order',
        'customer_partially_refunded_order',
        'cancelled_order',
        'failed_order',
    );

    foreach( $email_ids as $email_id ) {
        add_filter( "woocommerce_email_recipient_{$email_id}",  "additional_email_recipient" );
    }
}

function additional_email_recipient( $recipient ) {
    if ( is_admin() && isset($_GET['tab']) && $_GET['tab'] === 'email' ) 
        return $recipient;

    // HERE below define your additional email recipients
    $additional_recipient = array('additional1@example.com', 'additional2@example.com');

    $recipient .= ',' . implode(',', $additional_recipient);

    return $recipient;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

Related: [Target a specific email notification with the email id in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47741577/target-a-specific-email-notification-with-the-email-id-in-woocommerce/47742782#47742782)